# olap tool to be integrated with Visual 2012 Sql Server db

Tags: olap-cube

i need to know which tool should i use for my olap. i have a dataware house in sql visual 2012, and now i need to integrate a olap third party tool. Can anyone please help? THe tool represent the data in cubee and visual representation.